# CFD monitoring program

Tags: c++, python, linux

I run a lot of computational fluid dynamics (CFD) calculations. For many reasons, I would like to write a program which will monitor the output of the log file given by the CFD solver and adjust its control parameters accordingly. I have a few ideas but would like to ask for advice as to what would be the best way to do this.

My thoughts:

- could run the program constantly and import the convergence parameters at a fixed time interval or when the log file changes
- could use some system or platform specific utilities to monitor the CFD process
- the CFD runs in parallel on the same machine so (probably) will need a way to control the parallel processes (the CFD code I'm using is OpenFOAM which utilises OpenMPI to parallelise its processes)

For completeness, I run on Ubuntu 12.04 and would prefer the program to be written in C/C++ or alternatively Python.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you able to put an explicit administrative interface into the CFD solver, or is the code for that somehow not modifiable so you need to "control" it by reading and writing its output and input files?

Comment: In theory I can modify the CFD code as much as I want as it is fully accessible. I have done some code development for that and so I am pretty sure it is doable but I thought that perhaps an external application would be simpler to implement.

Now that you've mentioned it I will have a think about it a bit more, perhaps it is a better idea after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were me, I'd try to change the CFD code to be a library instead of an application, and then I'd expose it to Python.  Then I'd write a Python script that would invoke the library and get the results, iterating as needed.  If the CFD code doesn't take very long to run a single iteration, this will be more efficient than launching the CFD standalone program over and over.  And perhaps more importantly it will allow exchange of rich data between the CFD code and the supervisor, rather than only text files.

Comment: A single iteration usually takes between 20 seconds up to a few minutes, depending on the actual problem and solution method, etc. The total convergence is typically between 4-8 hours up to a day or two for a single run.
In terms of data exchange, through modifying the baseline C++ code it would be easier (I think) to get some more advanced data because it is stored in a set of objects forming a multilevel hierarchy (I'm sure you could deal with it in Python I just don't know how).
None the less I think it is a better route than writing a separate application.